# DJI MapView Application doesn't recognize RC/Drone

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, dji-sdk

Regarding Android-GSDemo-GoogleMap:
https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-GSDemo-GoogleMap
I've got the **Mavic Pro**,  my Android device is **Xiaomi Redmi 4A**, Android version **6.0.1** . I’m using Android Studio **3.0.1** .

After installing the GSDemo app (using the code in DJI's github and inserting the DJI SDK API key and google API key on the right places in the code) on my phone and connecting the device to the remote controller of the drone and turning the drone on (or using the simulator like the guide says) I get a message 'Register Success' in the GSDemo app but it seems that it is not recognizing the drone – its not showing the map at all, keep on saying 'Status: No Product Connected':
[image: screenshot]

I gave it all the required permissions including changing the connection to the remote controller of the drone from 'charging only' to PTP/MTP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should double check if you have set the default app behavior for a USB Accessory (your Mavic Pro) on your Xiaomi Redmi 4A correctly. Please check the FAQ of DJI Developer Website documentation:

https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/faq/index.html#how-do-i-reset-the-default-app-behavior-for-a-usb-accessory-dji-product-on-android-devices

When you connect your Android device to the RC, the Android device should ask which application to open and whether to make it default or not, then choose the GSDemo app.